Тест на внимательность из очереди проверок побледнел
Заметил интересный баг в очереди проверок: обратите внимание на скриншот ниже, на текст с проверочным вопросом словно наложили эффект прозрачности.



Всякий раз, как мне попадается тестовая проверка она имеет вот такой странный вид - ВСЕГДА и в любой очереди.
Даже не читая вопрос/ответ/правку я могу смело отклонять, кидать тревогу и т.д.
После жалобы на вопрос, система меня поздравляет с успешной проверкой и фильтр полупрозрачности слетает.



Сайт посещаю через - Chrome 124.0.6367.113
Как понимаю, так происходить не должно? 


Стал активнее проверять очередь на десктопе, проблема воспроизводится и в Opera One(версия: 109.0.5097.68), но в отличии от телефона не каждый раз.







Вы бы хоть выделили странность или описали подробно, в чем она заключается. Сходу я ничего не заметил

Дополнил вопрос. А так присмотритесь к первому и второму скриншоту. На первом скриншоте  можно увидеть что текст вопроса стал полупрозрачным\обесцветился.

На десктопе аналогичный эффект наблюдается?

@αλεχολυτ нет, только на телефоне.

@αλεχολυτ у меня наблюдался пару дней назад, давно не заходил, но прямо сразу наткнулся в очереди проверок на такую "прозрачную". Chrome, macOS

на десктопе наблюдается, я думала это так и должно быть (типа пока уровень у меня маленький и проверки "левые", будет выше и типа проверки круче станут...подумала я;), там много чего в правках странного, я пока только анализирую, потому как недавно начала свои правки, но эта проверка-полупрозрачная, это что то из ряда. причем порой даже нажимать не надо никуда, просто поздравляет...даже обидно, хочешь вклад внести, а тебя проверка ради проверки поздравляет (потеря времени порой, открыл-уведомление, лишнее кликабельные действия)

@Dev18 а какой у вас браузер? У меня на десктопе Opera и проверки штатно выглядят.

Chrome  Version 124.0.6367.119 (Build officiel) (64 bits) (Windows11)

Вообще такой эффект обычно накладывается на удаленные сообщения, которые после перезагрузки исчезают со страницы. Еще — на заминусованные ответы и сообщения из очередей, потенциально содержащие спам. А вот что оно означает в данном случае — непонятно.
